# Error connecting to SQL Server using pyodbc: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to connect to a SQL Server database using the pyodbc library in Python. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=localhost,1443;"
                      "Database=emp;"
                      "user=sam;"
                      "password=xyz@123;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 17.0};"
                      "Server=localhost;"
                      "Database=emp;"
                      "user=sam;"
                      "password=xyz@123;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

Tried both way also installed driver manually from microsoft based on code driver but no solution worked.

pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: There is no such thing as `SQL Server Native Client 17.0`, the latest version is 11 which was released, and deprecated, in *2012*, with support ending in 2014. Why aren't you using the latest [ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=linux#install-the-odbc-driver)?